# Redefinition of module 'minizip' Error

Tags: cocoapods, dependency-management

I am trying to create a COACOAPOD Library that uses IOS-Pods-DFU-Library as one of the dependency. I am using COACOAPODS for my dependency management. I am releasing my library as a binary framework and customers will integrate it with their app using COACOAPODS from localhost server with our custom podspec file that will download our binary framework from locahost server and resolve other dependencies.

Before Integrating iOSDFULibrary its used to works fine in the Customer applications. But after specifying iOSDFULibrary I am getting the following error

```
CustomerTest/Pods/Zip/Zip/minizip/module.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'minizip'
module minizip [system][extern_c] {
^
/Modules/xxxxxx/Pods/Zip/Zip/minizip/module.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module minizip [system][extern_c] {
^
:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Zip'
```

Am i missing something here? Any help will be appreciated.

Below are our sample podspec file and example how user includes our library.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name = "xxxxxx"
s.version = "1.0.0"
s.summary = "xxxxxx description ."
s.author = { "" => "" }
s.license = { :type => 'Apache-2.0', :file => 'LICENSE' }

s.ios.preserve_paths = 'xxxxxx.framework/*.bundle'

s.ios.deployment_target = "9.0"

s.source = { 
  :http => 'http://localhost:8000/xxxxxx.zip'
}  
s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'xxxxxx.framework'
s.dependency 'SSZipArchive', ' 2.1'
s.dependency 'XCGLogger', ' 6.0'
s.dependency "iOSDFULibrary", '4.1.1'

end
```

Customers will include our library by specifying above podsepec file path as below in their pod file

```
pod 'xxxxxx', :podspec => './xxxxxx.podspec'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the `minizip` module when using the `Zip` Cocoapod. For me the module was also declared double in both the Pods project as well as the app project. What fixed it for me [was this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55055371/250164).