# "Redefinition of module ..." when building for simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I have an iOS xcode project that builds fine when I have `Generic iOS Device` selected as my destination. However, when I select any of the simulator options I the build fails with many `Redefinition of module 'abcde'`, one error for every module defined in `iOS 11.4/usr/include/module.modulemap`.

The duplicate definitions are coming from `Simulator - iOS 11.4/usr/include/module.modulemap`. I've combed through my workspace/project settings and found no reference to the simulator. All the deployment targets are `iOS 11.4`.

It appears that when I build for the simulator it is including both the platform and simulator modules. How can I specify one or the other?

This problem popped up out of the blue about a day after adding cocoapods and swift code but I don't know if it is related. (The sdk/deployment targets for the pods are also `iOS 11.4` and swift version is 4 (except for Socket.IO which is using 3)).

My pods project is using the generated modulemap (I haven't edited it at all):

```
framework module Pods_MyProjectName {
  umbrella header "Pods-MyProjectName-umbrella.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

I've googled this problem over and over and haven't been able to find any solution for it. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, deleting the contents of the `Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder, deleting the pod's modulemap file, commenting out each line of the pod's modulemap file, removing all the code written since the problem began... I have the feeling that I'm looking in all the wrong places.

Comment: I came into work this morning and tried building for the simulator again to get the errors to show so I could go digging again. ... The problem has evaporated overnight without any visible trace of why. Gonna chalk this up to some configuration issue that was solved by a system reboot and move on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue with other pods. I assume the issue has to do with recursive dependecnies that are also imported explicitly. I tried all the same things as you did, although the only thing that helped me was to close xcode, run

```sh
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

and rebuild.

Comment: Hello, this did not work on me, do you have an other suggestion ?

Comment: check if the other pod in your project is using CommonCrypto inside itself. e.g. TPInAppReceipt

Answer (score 1):

I have just ran into this with a [CapacitorJS app](https://capacitorjs.com/). I have tried many of the solutions presented in the various forums and answers on here. What finally fixed it for me was I had the following environment variable set

```bash
CPATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include"
```

For me this was being exported in my `.zshrc` file so dependant on your shell I'd check for occurances of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a module that needs a modular header, you need to add to the following sentence to your `podfile`:

```
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
```